# Com definir a data limite no datepicker dinamico?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Tenho de definir uma data máxima para o calendarizo de forma dinâmica ou seja o mês DEVER ser a partir do ATUAL e no máximo UM ano posterior ao mes ATUAL.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".datepicker").datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      yearRange: "2019:2020"
   });
})
```

Comment: Seria do primeiro dia do mês atual até o último dia do mês daqui a 1 ano? Ex.: 01/10/2019 a 31/10/2020?

Comment: Apartir de hoje até um ano frente: 31/10/2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só você pegar o mês atual e o ano atual e usar um setter para alterar as opções `minDate` e `maxDate` do componente.

O `minDate` é simples, basta colocar o valor `"0"` que a data inicial será a data de hoje. No caso do `maxDate`, terá que pegar o mês atual e o ano atual através de um objeto `new Date()`:

```
var hoje = new Date(); // data de hoje
var mesAtual = hoje.getMonth()+1; // mês atual
var anoFinal = hoje.getFullYear()+1; // ano atual +1 = ano seguinte
```

Como hoje são 04/10/2019, os valores acima serão:

```
mesAtual -> 10
anoFinal -> 2020
```

Então você coloca esses valores em um outro objeto `new Date()` na opção `maxDate`:

```
new Date(anoFinal, mesAtual, 0)
```

Esse `0` significa que irá até o último dia do mês.

Ficaria assim o código:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
   });
   
   var hoje = new Date();
   var mesAtual = hoje.getMonth()+1;
   var anoFinal = hoje.getFullYear()+1;
   
   $("#datepicker").datepicker( "option", {
      "minDate": "0",
      "maxDate": new Date(anoFinal, mesAtual, 0)
   });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Essas configurações são bem explicitadas na **[documentação](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate)**.

Comment: grato pela resposta.